# Getting issue in log4j API logs generation

Tags: java, selenium, log4j

I am facing issue in generating logs on console.

Below is the snippents I am trying with :-

pom.xml:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

log4j.properties file :-I have kept this in src/main/resources folder

```
#Set level
log4j.rootCategory=debug, console, file  

# Appender which writes to console  
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender  
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %F %-5p [%t] %c{2} %L - %m%n

# Appender which writes to a file  
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\eclipse-workspace\CucumberWithTestNGForSelenium\application.log

# Defining maximum size of a log file
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10mb 
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10

log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p [%t] %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
```

And,below is my Test File

```
    package stepDefinition;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class GenerateLogs {

    final static Logger log=Logger.getLogger(GenerateLogs.class);
        @Test
        public void Test1()
        {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Mkap\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
            log.info("Launching chrome browser");
            driver.get("http://google.com");
                }

        @Test
        public void Test2()
        {
            System.out.println("Yeh!google has opened");
        }
    }
```

Can you please help why logs are not getting generated on console. Also,why  am not able to resolve errors of Logger class.

Comment: Please add the errors you are getting. How are you running this if you have errors?

Comment: Have you checked in **Reference Libraries** that log4j-1.2.17.jar is present?

Comment: I had just commented the Logger class line code in my Test.java file.I am not getting any error.The output is fine.Its just The logs are not getting generated on console along with the output

Comment: Which are the reference Libraries?I had just added dependency of log4j in MAVEN pom and can see the log4j jar under MAVEN dependency folder

Answer (score 0):

Try with root logger instead of rootCategory

```
 log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console,file
```

Find documentation here http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html